# What is wrong with this simple for loop?

Tags: java

I am so confused, I successfully did this half an hour ago, now I am stuck, I am not sure if I am missing a bracket, or a semi colon or what.

The error message I get is in the line where the for loop begins (should be line 3) and it states illegal start of expression.

```
    public class Apples {
           public static void main (String [] args) {
               for(int counter=1;counter<=10;counter=++){
                   System.out.println(counter + "apples.");
               }
           }
    }
```

Comment: correct syntax is counter++

Comment: Wow, yup, that's what it was. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `counter=++` to `counter++`.

`Java` `for`-loop?

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
  statement(s)
}
```

Your `for`-loop should follow this.

[Read More](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: +1 in the midst of all the other answers for taking the effort to show more theory in the answer

Answer (score 0):

The `counter=++` is the broken part. Change it to `counter++`

Answer (score 0):

`counter=++` is your problem. The format should be `counter++`

Answer (score 0):

Zion

your code should be like this

```
public class Apples {
       public static void main (String [] args) {
           for(int counter=1;counter<=10;counter++){
               System.out.println(counter + "apples.");
           }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use counter=counter+1 and you are good to go.